# How to train a tensorflow model that the output covers a huge range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've a dataset, where the output is logarithmic, I mean, it varies from values of 0.02 order to 15000 order, I should just train the model normally, or I should preprocess the output someway?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely get better results if you preprocess to ensure that the output is mostly within [0, 1]. Since your output is "logarithmic", it may also help to make the output more linear; that is, take the log of your original outputs and rescale such that the logs are in [0, 1].

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry for my ignorance in the topic since I'm new, but, I also have to normalize the target of the model, isn't it just for the features?

Comment: Feature normalization and output normalization serve different purposes. Feature normalization is used to ensure the features are more equally weighted, so that features with large ranges do not distort the weights. Output normalization is used to help avoid gradient explosion; a more linearly-distributed output will also help produce better gradients and probably train faster (assuming MSE loss).

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use a logarithmic activation function:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=lambda x: tf.math.log(x)),
])
```

Comment: Hello Nicolas, thanks for answering, I've a couple of questions with your answer, with that activation, the loss will compute normally? and to get the actual value of a prediction from a model with logarithmic activation, I have to antilog the prediction?